How to improve probability distribution fitting
I am trying to fit a distribution to daily percentage returns, and have got the following, where the p-val is low, suggesting it was not normally distributed. However, it's not perfect, and I try to tune manually the parameters but to no avail. How could I approach improving my model?


I suspect you have many observations that are exactly zero. Is that so, and is there maybe a reason for it?

Why do you expect a Gaussian to fit those data well?

To me this plot suggests a mixture of two distributions.

@Galen, how to identify which 2?

Based on he plot I would suggest a mixture distribution. Exactly which distributions to mix may be an exploratory modelling process, which I would suggest McElreath's material and Bayesian workflow.

But I guess a starting point would be to take a mixture of a Dirac delta distribution centered at zero with a normal distribution centered at zero.

Better models for returns are well covered in the literature (to reflect what you see here - heavy tails), though the distribution is usually asymmetric if you observe long enough to see a strong bear market, where the downside tail is heavier. If there's not a lot of heavily tied values (there might be with small-value stocks) I'd suggest as a first thought to try a t distribution with a low d.f., which is a common next step after a Gaussian. However, estimating d.f. is very difficult. You may need more bins (or an ecdf perhaps) to see what's going on very close to 0.

@Glen_b, please cite which literature in particular? Are they used in practice or just academic research?
